# How to use RainTPL?

Tags: php, templates

I'm trying to use the 'include' tag from RainTPL but it's not working, I can't figure out why.

My server setup is a UniServer installation with apache and php. I have tried php code to test the setup and it worked.

```
    <?php
    include "inc/rain.tpl.class.php"; //include Rain TPL
    raintpl::$tpl_dir = "layout/"; // template directory
    raintpl::$cache_dir = "tmp/"; // cache directory
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Ezbuy - Compras Inteligentes - Aguardem</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="comingsoon.css" type="text/css">
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>

    <body>

        {include="layout/header"}

        <section class="main">
            <div class="box">
                <article>
                    <header>
                        <h2>Facilidade, Preço & Segurança</h2>
                    </header>
                    <p>Cadastre-se e descubra uma forma fácil de comprar, sem necessidade de longas pesquisas pela internet.
                    Você pode escolher os produtos oferecidos com o menor preço.
                    Vendedores qualificados e método de pagamento seguro.</p>
                </article>
            </div>
        </section>

      <section class="row">
        <div class="boxrow">
            <article class="column" style="padding-right: 10%;">
                <center><img src="interest.png" height="64px" style="padding-top: 50px;" /></center>
                <header class="headercolumn">
                    <h2>Apenas o que interessa</h2>
                </header>
                <p>Find local favorites, new menu items, and global recommendations. Check the Forkly DishScore&trade; to see what’s good at a glance; or search every dish and detail to plan ahead.<p>
            </article>
            <article class="column">
                <center><img src="money.png" height="64px" style="padding-top: 50px;" /></center>
                <header class="headercolumn">
                    <h2>Pague quanto quiser</h2>
                </header>
                <p>Escolha o valor que deseja pagar pelo produto e aguarde uma oferta.<p>
            </article>
        </div>
      </section>

      <div class="clear"/>

        <!--<footer style="height: 300px;">
            <p class="copyright">&copy Copyright 2013 Feiler IT.</p>
        </footer>-->

    </body>

</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just use `{include="header"}` as you have already told Rain to use `layout` folder as template directory... what you are currently doing is trying to include `layout/layout/header.html`

By the way.. you should not include HTML and PHP in the same file... you should use an index.php file to initialize the Rain instance and then call the `draw('template')` method and put all the html in the file `layout/template.html`